# Windows phone not recognized

Tags: windows-7, windows-phone

I upgraded my Dell Venue Pro on someone else's computer and since then I'm unable to get it to be recognized by my own computer.
Its a T-mobile version operator-unlocked developer-unlocked device and I'm on Windows 7.
Can someone please suggest what to do( except hard resetting the device ).

It has mango and Dell's post-mango firmware update.

Edit: If it helps to know, I upgraded to Mango on my own computer using the leaked Mango build. I upgraded Dell firmware on someone else's computer.

After using ghostbuster to remove useless driver it now says that my device is not recognized 
as it has malfunctioned. I installed a new copy of Windows 8 developer preview and it says the same. Does this mean that my device actually has something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to connect it? Cable, Bluetooth...?

Comment: I'm connecting it using usb cable.

Comment: You may Ned to reflash your device with either the current or an older version of the software as it may be that something did not flash quite right or some settings didn't reset after the flash.  Some instructions for the process are at [Modaco](http://android.modaco.com/topic/323602-how-to-install-official-dell-22-upgradepkg/) but you would have to find the correct image for your phone.

Comment: Thanks. My only fear is that if it turns out that my device is actually malfunctioning in terms of hardware then I'll be stuck with Windows Phone 7 and will have no way to upgrade to 7.5 till I can get the hardware repaired. I know it sounds stupid and I'm not going to blame you later, but are you reasonably confident that flashing problems is what this is? If you say yes, I'll hard reset my phone the first thing, Without worrying about the consequences. (Oh please say yes!! :) )

Comment: Did a reset, somehow it didn't reset to factory settings = 7.0 and is Mango right now. Anyway, thanks for your help. I guess its better than not trying anything!

Comment: Just to clarify, my problem still isn't solved, which is that I'm still unable to connect my phone to my computer.